# What do I do with the facebook access token?

Tags: php, ios, mysql, swift, facebook

I set up Facebook login with my swift, php, mysql ios app and am storing basic user info in NSUserdefaults, so I can check whether the user is logged in or not. But when reading the Facebook docs, I came across the Facebook token to check if the user is logged in. Would I/should I use this. I assume not since when the user signs in through Facebook I would take the same route as regular sign in and just store the Facebook info in NSUserDefaults and just authorize through that.

Comment: An access token is an opaque string that identifies a user, app, or Page and can be used by the app to make graph API calls. Because of privacy checks, the majority of API calls on Facebook need to include an access token.

Comment: READ THIS-:https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

> Access token is for authentication

Access token is required for getting further info of the user. In few cases if your application contains both login **login via Email** of **login via Facebook** you need token. like below you get data:

```
if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
                    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email, picture.width(180).height(180)"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                        if (error == nil){
                            self.fbAccesstoken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString //save your access token and in result object you get "id,name, first_name, last_name, email, picture (180*180)"
                            completion(result as AnyObject,nil)
                        }
                    })
                }
```

Comment: Yes I understand that, but my question is after they login for the first time and I save their info in my db, should I also store that info in the userdefault so I have the user object when I check if the fb access token is valid.

Comment: Yes dear save access token for auto login, if you donot perform any option toke will expire within 60 days.